# What's the correct way of converting values?

Tags: groovy, griffon

I was trying to make my model strings to be always uppercase, so I tried to use converter and reverseConverter to do this job. Using the mutual option I got hitted by [this topic](http://griffon-user.3225736.n2.nabble.com/Re-groovy-user-IllegalStateException-Attempt-to-mutate-in-notification-exception-when-using-mutual-b-td7578244.html#a7578250).

Witch leads to my question. Is this the right use case to converter? Without the mutual the value was converted only in the model, and didn't update the view.

Can I use the [DocumentFilter](http://www.kodejava.org/examples/225.html) approach?

#### Example

```
 textField(columns: 3, text: bind("score", target: m, 
            converter: { it.isEmpty()? 0: Integer.parseInt(it) },
            reverseConverter: { String.valueOf(it) },
            mutual: true))
```

Comment: I use `JFormattedTextField` to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid `converter:` and `reverseConverter:` only work with unidirectional bindings at the moment.